# iPhone SDK - Display a UIView from the AppDelegate over a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I hope my title makes sense.

I have an iPhone app uses the standard `UINavigationController` approach to push new view controllers and let the user navigate as they wish.

Now, in my `AppDelegate` I have a method which runs on a timer, which calls out to a web service. If this service comes back with a particular response, I want to be able to display a `UIView` (essentially a custom alert box, but I don't want to use the `UIAlertView` class).

**How can I get this UIView (defined in the `AppDelegate`) to display on the `UIWindow` - and therefore on top of any and all views which have been pushed by the navigation controller?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your AppDelegate is supposed to have a property `window`. A window is a view, so you can do `[self.window addSubview:newView];`

Note: Also UIViews, that are added to the app's view hierarchy have a property `window`, pointing to the same object. So a view controller can reach the window without dealing with the app delegate.

```
[controller.view.window addSubview:overlayView];
```

Make sure this is after you have set the `rootViewController`. Also you might need `[self.window bringSubviewToFront: newView]`

Comment: You probably meant `[controller.view.window addSubview:overlayView];`?

Comment: hmm, probably. so long ago…

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to grab the topmost view controller on the navigation controller's stack then use that to present modal the new view... set up a reference in the custom alert view so that it can dismiss itself...

```
CustomAlert * alert = [[CustomAlert alloc] initWithwhatever];
UIViewController * currentVC = navigationController.topViewController;
alert.delegate = currentVC;
[currentVC presentModalViewController:alert animated:YES];


//then dismiss from the alert logic with 

[delegate dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: This will not work, because views under the modal view will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this one:

```
[UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window addSubview:yourViewController.view]
```

Comment: Ugly. Why not leverage objc-2.0 and go `[UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window addSubview:]` instead?